# HTML 5 CSS Footer Stacking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code in my footer on a liquid website. Only problem is, the 3 columns in the footer are stacking on top of each other (vertically) rather than going horizontally. Was wondering if anyone could see what the problem is with the code.

```css
#footer .column {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#footer .column div {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="column">
    <div>Image 1</div>
    <div>Image 2</div>
    <div>Image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're floating the column (containing all three components), but not the components themselves.

Also, 33.3% widths plus 10px (either side) margins on each element will almost certainly exceed 100% of the container width. I've adjusted that.

```css
#footer .column {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#footer .column div{
  margin: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 31.3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="column">
    <div>Image 1</div>
    <div>Image 2</div>
    <div>Image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floating `.column`, you should float each column

```css
#footer > .column {
    overflow: hidden; /* clear float */
}
#footer > .column > div {
    float: left;
}
```

```css
#footer .column {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#footer > .column > div {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="column">
    <div>Image 1</div>
    <div>Image 2</div>
    <div>Image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, note that the margin isn't included in `width: 33.3%`, so they won't fit in a single line.

Then, you can use flexboxes:

```css
#footer .column {
  display: flex;
}
#footer > .column > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
#footer .column {
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#footer > .column > div {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="column">
    <div>Image 1</div>
    <div>Image 2</div>
    <div>Image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```